# Xcode & passing command line arguments

Tags: c, macos, command-line-arguments

I just started working with C & Xcode and I've run into a little difficulty.

All I want to do is read a file from the command line and see the output in the terminal.
I think my problem lies with the path to the file that I want to read in. I'm using a Mac and the file is on my desktop, so the path should be `Users/myName/Desktop/words.txt`. Is this correct?

This is my code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char* argv[]){

    if(argc == 1){
        NSLog(@" you must pass at least one arguement");
        return 1;
    }
    NSLog(@"russ");
    FILE*  wordFile = fopen(argv[1] , "r");
    char word[100];

    while (fgets(word,100,wordFile)) {

        NSLog(@" %s is %d chars long", word,strlen(word));

    }

    fclose(wordFile);
    return 0;

}//main
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the path to a file in OS X, an easy way to get it is to just drag the file into the Terminal.app window where you are typing the command.  Voila!

Answer (score 2):

The path to the desktop is `/Users/[username]/Desktop/`

`~/Desktop/` is a user-agnostic way of denoting this, `~` represents the current users home directory. It must be expanded using a method like [`stringByExpandingTildeInPath`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByExpandingTildeInPath)

Not sure about using C# (I've never used it on Mac OS X), but in Objective-C/Cocoa, you would do..

```
// Get array with first index being path to desktop
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDesktopDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

// Get the first element
NSString *desktopPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

// Append words.txt to path
NSString *theFilePath = [desktopPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"words.txt"];

NSLog(@"%@", theFilePath);
```

This is the most robust way of getting the Desktop path, as a user could technically move their Desktop folder else where (although this is pretty unlikely). Another valid option is to use the NSString method `stringByExpandingTildeInPath`:

```
NSString *desktop = [@"~/Desktop" stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
NSString *theFile = [desktop stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"words.txt"]
```

As I said, both those are in Objective-C, but it shouldn't be hard to translate to C#, assuming you can get at the Cocoa libraries.

---

The code you posted works correctly:

```
dbr:.../build/Debug $ ./yourcode ~/Desktop/words.txt 
yourcode[2106:903] russ
yourcode[2106:903]  this is words.txt is 17 chars long
```

Your terminal automatically expands the `~/` tilda path

Answer (score 0):

Close... it's

`/{Volume}/Users/myName/Desktop/words.txt`

... where {Volume} is the name of your hard drive. You can also try using:

`~/Desktop/words.txt`

... where `~` is understood to mean "your home directory", but this might not resolve correctly.

Comment: that did not solve my problem (either suggestion) I used:
/Macintosh HD/Users/russ/Desktop/words.txt 
&
~/Desktop/words.txt

Answer (score 0):

(Note - this appears to be a C question, not a C# question)

Actually, you can do:

/Users/myName/Desktop/words.txt

You don't have to give the path to the volume.

However, to get the full path in C you'd do something like:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
char *home, *fullPath;

home = getenv("HOME");

fullPath = strcat(home, "/Desktop/words.txt");
```

The issue you're running into with passing the filename as an argument is that you need to set the current working directory to the place where the file exists.